# Laravel api config custom validation to not crash

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

So I have laravel configured as api and as seperate app I have vue. In Laravel I have cors set up:

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
'allowedHeaders' => ['Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With'],
'allowedMethods' => ['*'], // ex: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE']
'exposedHeaders' => [],
'maxAge' => 60,
```

and I have those 2 routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function () {
    Route::post('/auth/register', 'UserController@register');
    Route::post('/auth/login', 'UserController@login');
});
```

UserController@register

```
public function register(UserRegister $request)
{
    return 'hello';
}
```

and UserRegister:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:50',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:100',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required' => 'Name is required',
            'name.max' => 'Name can only contain up to 50 characters',

            'email.required' => 'Email address is required',
            'email.email' => 'Email address must be a right format',
            'email.unique' => 'Email address must be unique',
            'email.max' => 'Email can only contain up to 100 characters',

            'password.required' => 'Password is required',
            'password.min' => 'Password must be minimum of 6 characters',
            'password.confirmed' => 'Password does not match password confirmation',
        ];
    }
```

Here's my vue:

```
  data() {
    return {
      form: new Form({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        password_confirmation: ''
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      this.form.post('https://webuilder.app/api/auth/register')
        .then(response => alert('Wahoo!'));
    }
  }
```

my form class:

```
import Errors from './error.js';

class Form {
  /**
   * Create a new Form instance.
   *
   * @param {object} data
   */
  constructor(data) {
    this.originalData = data;

    for (let field in data) {
      this[field] = data[field];
    }

    this.errors = new Errors();
  }


  /**
   * Fetch all relevant data for the form.
   */
  data() {
    let data = {};

    for (let property in this.originalData) {
      data[property] = this[property];
    }

    return data;
  }


  /**
   * Reset the form fields.
   */
  reset() {
    for (let field in this.originalData) {
      this[field] = '';
    }

    this.errors.clear();
  }


  /**
   * Send a POST request to the given URL.
   * .
   * @param {string} url
   */
  post(url) {
    return this.submit('post', url);
  }


  /**
   * Send a PUT request to the given URL.
   * .
   * @param {string} url
   */
  put(url) {
    return this.submit('put', url);
  }


  /**
   * Send a PATCH request to the given URL.
   * .
   * @param {string} url
   */
  patch(url) {
    return this.submit('patch', url);
  }


  /**
   * Send a DELETE request to the given URL.
   * .
   * @param {string} url
   */
  delete(url) {
    return this.submit('delete', url);
  }


  /**
   * Submit the form.
   *
   * @param {string} requestType
   * @param {string} url
   */
  submit(requestType, url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios[requestType](url, this.data())
        .then(response => {
          this.onSuccess(response.data);

          resolve(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.onFail(error);

          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }


  /**
   * Handle a successful form submission.
   *
   * @param {object} data
   */
  onSuccess(data) {
    alert(data.message); // temporary

    this.reset();
  }


  /**
   * Handle a failed form submission.
   *
   * @param {object} errors
   */
  onFail(errors) {
    this.errors.record(errors);
  }
}
```

export default Form;

error.js:

```
class Errors {
  /**
   * Create a new Errors instance.
   */
  constructor() {
    this.errors = {};
  }


  /**
   * Determine if an errors exists for the given field.
   *
   * @param {string} field
   */
  has(field) {
    return this.errors.hasOwnProperty(field);
  }


  /**
   * Determine if we have any errors.
   */
  any() {
    console.log(this.errors);
    return Object.keys(this.errors).length > 0;
  }


  /**
   * Retrieve the error message for a field.
   *
   * @param {string} field
   */
  get(field) {
    console.log(this.errors[field]);
    if (this.errors[field]) {
      return this.errors[field][0];
    }
  }


  /**
   * Record the new errors.
   *
   * @param {object} errors
   */
  record(errors) {
    this.errors = errors;
    console.log(this.errors);
  }


  /**
   * Clear one or all error fields.
   *
   * @param {string|null} field
   */
  clear(field) {
    if (field) {
      delete this.errors[field];

      return;
    }

    this.errors = {};
  }
}

export default Errors;
```

So when I make a post request after filling in form, I get this:

> xhr.js?ec6c:178 XHR finished loading: OPTIONS
>   "https://webuilder.app/api/auth/register". dispatchXhrRequest @
>   xhr.js?ec6c:178 xhrAdapter @ xhr.js?ec6c:12 dispatchRequest @
>   dispatchRequest.js?c4bb:59 Promise resolved (async) request @
>   Axios.js?5e65:51 Axios.(anonymous function) @ Axios.js?5e65:71 wrap @
>   bind.js?24ff:9 (anonymous) @ form.js?b695:94 submit @ form.js?b695:93
>   post @ form.js?b695:52 onSubmit @ register.vue?0a4c:65 boundFn @
>   vue.esm.js?efeb:190 submit @ register.vue?c4f0:44 invoker @
>   vue.esm.js?efeb:2004 fn._withTask.fn._withTask @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1802
>   19:36:52.962 webuilder.app/api/auth/register:1 POST
>   https://webuilder.app/api/auth/register 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
>   19:36:52.962 webuilder.app/api/auth/register:1 POST
>   https://webuilder.app/api/auth/register 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
>   19:36:52.963 register:1 Failed to load
>   https://webuilder.app/api/auth/register: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 422. Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js?16d0:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?ec6c:87)  Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js?16d0:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?ec6c:87)
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js?16d0:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?ec6c:87) createError @ createError.js?16d0:16 handleError @ xhr.js?ec6c:87 Promise rejected
>   (async) onSubmit @ register.vue?0a4c:66 boundFn @ vue.esm.js?efeb:190
>   submit @ register.vue?c4f0:44 invoker @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2004
>
> 19:36:53.000 XHR failed loading: POST
>   "https://webuilder.app/api/auth/register".

when I check in the response I do get the response with all the validation errors, but these errors make my post crash,and validation error are not being displayed when I do console.log(error) on .catch in axios. Any help here?

Comment: Did you apply the Laravel CORS middleware to your api group?

Comment: of course, otherwise OPTIONS request would fial

Comment: Okay @Jeff I restarted the server and now console.log(error) gives me: Error: Request failed with status code 422
    at createError (createError.js?16d0:16)
    at settle (settle.js?db52:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?ec6c:77), but not the actual json

Comment: which in network tab looks like this: {message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
errors
:
{password: ["Password must be minimum of 6 characters"]}
password
:
["Password must be minimum of 6 characters"]
message
:
"The given data was invalid."